# Byte '\x09' terminates the string?

Tags: c, string, echo, command-line-arguments

I found an unexpected (to me) behaviour between my program and the `echo` command.

Here's my source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("argv length: %d\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    return 0;
}
```

If I use the byte `0x09` in the argument, it will terminate the string, as if I used the byte `0x00`.

Examples:

```
user@linux:~$ ./a.out `echo -e '\x41'`
argv length: 1

user@linux:~$ ./a.out `echo -e '\x41\x41'`
argv length: 2

user@linux:~$ ./a.out `echo -e '\x41\x09'`
argv length: 1

user@linux:~$ ./a.out `echo -e '\x41\x09\x41'`
argv length: 1
```

Can someone explain why does this occur?

Comment: Enhance your program and printf all arguments and not only the first one and you'll understand.

Comment: `argv` is split by whitespace; I'm guessing `\x09` is whitespace...

Comment: 0x09 (TAB) is considered as a a whitespace character by the shell. It has nothing to do with the C language.

Comment: And what does `./a.out  '\x41\x09\x41'` give?

Comment: Use `int a; for (a=1; a<argc; a++) printf("argv length: %d\n", strlen(argv[a]));` and then try input `'\x41\x09\x42'`, expect to see 2 lines of output, each length 1.  Now try `'\x41\x0\x42'`.  What do you think will happen?

Comment: You don't print the lenght of the `argv` array, but only the second argument. `printf` `argc`, too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x09` is the tabulation char. It does not terminate a string, but here you ran your arguments without protecting them.

In the `'\x41\x09'` case, the tab char was just stripped by the shell.

In the `'\x41\x09\0x41'` case, the tab char acted as an argument separator, thus creating another argument.

The quoting was consumed by `echo`, but `echo` loses it when echoing back, hence the need to adding another quoting.

Try that:

```
./a.out `echo -e "'\x41\x09\x41'"`
```

you'll see you get a 3-byte sole argument

Comment: Just to add something: your last command doesn't work as expected because the `"` was considered as 'part' of the argument (like the tab character). That one worked: `./a.out "\`echo -e '\x41\x09\x41'\`"`. Perhaps you should edit your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @J.Doe strange as `echo -e "'\x41\x09\x41'"` echoes a quoted `'A    A'`. I'll check that tonight (for the completeness of the answer).

Answer (score 2):

`\x09` is a tab, so it's like feeding your program with:

```
./a.out A    A
```

And the length of the first argument is 1.